# Codewars Challenge - JavaScript - Find the first non-consecutive number in Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, null

[Link to Codewars challenge](https://www.codewars.com/kata/58f8a3a27a5c28d92e000144/train/javascript)

This is very basic, but for some reason, I can't figure out why I'm not able to return `null` when there are **not** any non-consecutive numbers in an array. My code works fine when the array is not totally consecutive:

```js
function firstNonConsecutive(arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i + 1] - arr[i] !== 1) {
      return arr[i + 1];
    }
  }
  return null;
}


console.log(firstNonConsecutive([ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]));
```

But if the array *is* consecutive, i.e. like this:

```js
function firstNonConsecutive(arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i + 1] - arr[i] !== 1) {
      return arr[i + 1];
    }
  }
  return null;
}

console.log(firstNonConsecutive([ 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 ]));
```

You can see that it returns `undefined` instead of `null`. Why isn't it returning null? The return is outside of the for-loop.

I tried to create an initial check to see if the array is not consecutive, like this:

```js
function firstNonConsecutive(arr) {
  let newArr = [];
  for (let j = arr[0]; j < arr[arr.length - 1]; j++) {
    newArr.push(j);
  }
  //check if arr does not contain consecutive characters
  if (String(arr) !== String(newArr)) {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (arr[i + 1] - arr[i] !== 1) {
        return arr[i + 1];
      }
    }
  }
  else {
    return null;
  }
}
console.log(firstNonConsecutive([ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]));
```

But it did not make a difference. Any ideas?

Comment: `i < arr.length`  and then `arr[i + 1]` will be undefined.  you will want `i < arr.length - 1`

Comment: You're iterating over the entire array but accessing `arr[i + 1]`, which means the last iteration's test will always fail, then return `arr[i + 1]` which is `undefined`.

Comment: @Keith thanks, yeah this is the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest to start from the second item and check the element and the element before.

This approach does not change the length to check for and it omits the problem to check non existent elements.

```js
function firstNonConsecutive(arr) {
    for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i - 1] + 1 !== arr[i]) return arr[i];
    }
    return null;
}

console.log(firstNonConsecutive([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]));
console.log(firstNonConsecutive([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]));
```

Comment: Will perfectly work for consecutive numbers, listed in **ascending** order.

Answer (score 2):

You may try to [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) the gap:

```
const firstNonConsecutive = arr => arr.find((n,i,s) => i && n-s[i-1] > 1)
```

So, it's modified version that'll pass arrays without gaps and arrays with negatives, would look like that:

```js
const src1 = [1,2,3,4,6,7,8],
      src2 = [ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 ],
      src3 = [ -4, -3, -2, 0, 1, 3, 4, 5 ],
      firstNonConsecutive = arr => (
        gap = arr.find((n,i,s) => i && Math.max(n,s[i-1])-Math.min(n,s[i-1]) > 1), 
        gap === undefined ? null : gap
      )
      
console.log(firstNonConsecutive(src1))
console.log(firstNonConsecutive(src2))
console.log(firstNonConsecutive(src3))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

While my answer may appear a bit overcomplicated due to `Math.min()`/`Math.max()` usage, it'll work for ***consecutive numbers listed in descending order*** just as well.

Answer (score 2):

I have solution like this:

```js
function firstNonConNum(arr) {
    const result = arr
        .find((element, i) => {
        if (i < 1) {
            return false
        }
        if ((element - arr[i - 1]) !== 1) {
            return true;
        }
    })
    if (result !== undefined) {
        return result
    }
    return null;
}

console.log(firstNonConNum([-2, 0, 1, 2, 6, 4, 5, 6, 7 ]));
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is work, but i think, that this code is not so good.

```
function firstNonConsecutive (arr) {
  if (arr.length == 1 || arr.length == 0) {
    return null;
  } else { 
    let count = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
      if (arr[i+1] - arr[i] !== 1) {
        count.push(arr[i+1])
      }
    } 
    if (count[0] == undefined) {
      return null
    } else {
      return count[0]
    }
  }
  console.log(arr);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).